# Inserting into a View Error

Tags: c#, .net, view, entity-framework-6

I am getting the following error, when i try to insert into a view using Entity Framerwork (6):

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

This is happening on

```
 context.SaveChanges()
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It means, that the query does not insert anything... probably you forgot to set status of any entity so it has tracked as not changed... show more code

Comment: Here's the insert method: 
public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }